# The difference between '=' and 'append' in list in this example?

Tags: python, list

I know list is a kind of changeable collection of data object ,but why the output is different.
I thought they should be the same.

```sh
a = [1]
b = a
b = [1,2]
print(a)
```

output:

```sh
[1]
```

```sh
a = [1]
b = a
b.append(2)
print(a)
```

output:

```sh
[1,2]
```

Comment: first case,  new list diferrent memory address. Second case, assignt b same memory adress than a, they point same data

Comment: In the first example when you do `b = [1, 2]` that creates a *new* list and assigns it to b. In the second example, there's only one list and a and b both reference it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
a = [1]
b = a
b = [1,2]
print(a)
```

When you do this, the value for `b` is reassigned therefore losing the connection with `a`.

```py
a = [1]
b = a
b.append(2)
print(a)
```

But here, appending to `b` means the same list in the memory is appended a value. Since `a` and `b` still refer to the same memory, printing `a` results the same as `b` since they two are just two different aliases for the list.

Answer (score 4):

In the first example you are overwriting:

```
a=[1]
b=a     # b=[1] and b=a
b=[1,2] # b=[1,2] but not a
```

in the second example you apply a function built into lists:

```
a=[1]
b=a         # b=[1] and b=a
b.append(1) # applies append to b which is a so a.append is done
```